# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to interprete URL on POSTMAN

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I have this task to perform.

I am given this URL (GET Request) on POSTMAN to develop something similar using ASP.NET Core-6 Web API.

> {{BASE_URL}}/api/v1/educationsector/transaction/{{TESTSECTOR}}?fromDate=20210224&toDate=20210224

The sample URL is like this:

> https://testing.com:9443/educationgateway/api/v1/educationsector/transaction/2020076821?fromDate=20200724&toDate=20200724

What do **{{TESTSECTOR}}** and **{{BASE_URL}}** imply?

Then, since fromDate and toDate are parameters, is it that {{TESTSECTOR}} is also a parameter?

I don't really understand.

How do I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: you can configure params in postman , Base URL may be to test with multiple environment .

Comment: And you can configure and automate tests in postman hence you can use params

Comment: @Ghassen - What does {{TESTSECTOR}} imply? Is it also a paramenter?  The sample URL look like this:   https://testing.com:9443/educationgateway/api/v1/educationsector/transaction/2020076821?fromDate=20200724&toDate=20200724

Comment: yes it is a param

Comment: educationsector replaces the TESTSECTOR param

Comment: check the link https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/

Comment: another example suppose you have multiple request and you have to set a token for all request, you have just to create a variable and update it for all your requests

Answer (score 0):

In your case，`https://testing.com:9443/educationgateway`is the base url，`TESTSECTOR`is a parameter in route，fromdate and todate which are behind `？` are arguments in query

In ASP.NET Core Web API, arguments passed in route could be accessed with

```
var routedatadic = HttpContext.Request.RouteValues;
```

Arguments passed in query could be accessed with

```
var querydatacollection = HttpContext.Request.Query;
```

For example: I configured the route of method:

```
[Route("[Controller]/[Action]/Section/{Section1}/{Section2}")]
```

And I tried with the url:

```
https://localhost:44324/WeatherForecast/WeatherForecast/Get/Section/s1/s2?fromdata=fromdata&todata=todata
```

The result：

[image]

[image]

For more details,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0)